# Dynamically generating DC.JS charts from json list, challenge with valueAccessor

Tags: jquery, dc.js

I'm trying to generate dc charts dynamically from an array which generates these charts. Everything works good so far but I'm stuck on outputting a custom calculation in the valueAccessor. I tried to split up objects and functions (like + - /) in order to have all these behaving differently. Latest jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yccu/L7k3sunz/18/  Here's a piece of the code but I'm sure in the wrong direction;

```
.valueAccessor(function(p){
var x = {}
var v = ''
cl_val.algorithm.forEach(function(f,i) {
if(cl_val.algorithm[i].dim){
  x = x && p.value[cl_val.algorithm[i].dim];
}
   if(cl_val.algorithm[i].func){
  x = x && [cl_val.algorithm[i].func];
}
    });

  console.log(x)
    return x;

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked by pushing these in an array and then use eval function and a join.

```
  . valueAccessor(function(p){
        var ret = [];
        cl_val.algorithm.forEach(function(f,i) {
    if(cl_val.algorithm[i].dim){
        ret.push(p.value[cl_val.algorithm[i].dim]);
    }
    if(cl_val.algorithm[i].func){
        ret.push(eval([cl_val.algorithm[i].func]));
    }               
        });
  console.log (eval(ret.join(' ')))
        return eval(ret.join(' '));

 });
```